# Rails4 form dynamic read only field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails form that needs at field to be readonly or not depending on the checkbox the user clicks. So far I have

```
<%= form_for @weight, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class= "modal-body">
     <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" onclick="ReadOnly()"></input>
     <%= f.label :weight_number, class="control-label"%>
     <%= f.number_field :weight_number, :readonly => true, class="form-control"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
 <script>
    function ReadOnly(){
      if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked{ 
        //make the number field editable
      }
    }
 </script>
```

Is there a clean and concise why do this. I've never had to manipulate a ruby line via JavaScript before, but I would like to toggle that numbe field between :readonly => true and :readonly => false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="suspended" id="checkbox1" value="test"/>
<input type="number" name="weight_number" id="weight_number_id">
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
      $("#weight_number_id").attr('readonly', 'true');
    }
    else {
      $("#weight_number_id").removeAttr('readonly');
    }
  });
  //triger change event in case checkbox checked when user accessed page
  $("#checkbox1").trigger("change")
});
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cc5T3/181/)

Comment: This works great! I guess my only question now is how to display the current value in the number input. This is an edit form in rails that was being populate with that value, but now with the new html format how would I display that value in the field? Nevermind, I forgot to add a value into the number field input! thanks for your help!

Comment: @MeganWoodruff you don't need to change html, add `id` and remove `read_only` in your field like `<%= f.number_field :weight_number, :id => "weight_number_id" , class="form-control"%>`